# "User Not Found" message after logging in to Oracle Retail Central Office application

Tags: oracle

**Application Version**- 12.0.9

**Problem**- After logging in to the oracle retail Central office application, I am getting "user not found" message on the screen even though my user has been added to required super access groups within my company. Before trying to log in, we have deployed the centraloffice.ear from zip artifact of oracle retail central office from jenkins pipeline to the required application server.

**What I've tried**-

1. Tried to log in using the credentials of other active users as well (these credentials are working on other 2 instances of this application deployed on other different application servers). This third instance is deployed on the third server where it should be deployed as expected.
2. Tried to find the root cause by checking the central office logs while logging in and logging out but there is no log message available related to the **user not found** issue, only logout is getting logged.

Comment: This problem has been fixed

Comment: It'd be nice if you posted the solution as an answer, for future people who may have this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through the authentication implementation of Central Office at my company  and found that my user was missing from a required table due to which the issue was happenning.